# Call Comsol from Fortran

Tags: fortran, comsol

Is it possible to call Comsol from Fortran?

I have found that it is possible to call Comsol from Matlab, and Matlab from Fortran. However, is it possible to skip Matlab?

I want to just use a simple 2D axisymmetric FEM solve.

Answer (score 0):

Comsol was essentially a toolbox to matlab before, that’s where the support originates from.

You could use java to call your fortran code, and later comsol, and then back to fortran again. Starting point: http://www.csharp.com/javacfort.html

Alternative solution is to use the mex-interface to run fortran from matlab (fairly simple actually). Then call comsol with the comsolmatlab-connection, and so on.